# How to make Twitter login in iOS APP?

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, authentication, ios9

How to make login with twitter in iOS app?
  I didn't find it in Twitter Developer.
    Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [fabric](https://fabric.io) to enable login using Twitter which will enable you a lot more functionalities than authentication like Crashlytics (crash reporting tool)

There are two ways for authentication

**1.Log in Button**

```
TWTRLogInButton* logInButton = [TWTRLogInButton buttonWithLogInCompletion:^(TWTRSession* session, NSError* error) {
  if (session) {
      NSLog(@"signed in as %@", [session userName]);
  } else {
      NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
  }
}];
logInButton.center = self.view.center;
[self.view addSubview:logInButton];
```

**2. Log in Method**

```
[[Twitter sharedInstance] logInWithCompletion:^(TWTRSession *session, NSError *error) {
  if (session) {
      NSLog(@"signed in as %@", [session userName]);
  } else {
      NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
  }
}];
```

Here is the URL for the [documentation](https://docs.fabric.io/ios/twitter/authentication.html)